# Dynamically generating id to a table row tag through jsp

Tags: javascript, java, html, jakarta-ee

I want to assign a unique id to each  tag in HTML  using JSP.

Code Snippet...

```
 <%

        ArrayList<HospitalDTO> list=(ArrayList<HospitalDTO>)request.getAttribute("arrayList");
        for(HospitalDTO hsp:list)
        {
            long no=hsp.getNumber();
            //session.setAttribute("contactNumber",no);
            String name=hsp.getName();
            Date nextDD=hsp.getNextDD();
            Date lastDD=hsp.getLastDD();

            out.println("<tr><td class='text-center' >"+no+"</td><td class='text-center'>"+name+"</td><td class='text-center'>"+lastDD+

                    "</td><td class='text-center'>"+nextDD+"</td><td class='text-center'><input type='submit' class='btn btn-info' value='Notify Donor'></td></tr>");
        }

    %>
```

Comment: create a variable using random number or some unique number.

Comment: But how we would give id to the td tag

Comment: "<tr><td class='text-center' " + 'id = ' +  uniqueid  + ">"  something similar to this will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `for` loop to generate each HTML row element. So you can just use row index to ensure a unique ID. For example, the following code generates ID for each `tr` element starting from "row_0":

```
<%

    ArrayList<HospitalDTO> list=(ArrayList<HospitalDTO>)request.getAttribute("arrayList");
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        HospitalDTO hsp = list.get(i);
        long no=hsp.getNumber();
        //session.setAttribute("contactNumber",no);
        String name=hsp.getName();
        Date nextDD=hsp.getNextDD();
        Date lastDD=hsp.getLastDD();
        String rowId = "row_" + i;

        out.println("<tr id='" + rowId + "'><td class='text-center' >"+no+"</td><td class='text-center'>"+name+"</td><td class='text-center'>"+lastDD+

                "</td><td class='text-center'>"+nextDD+"</td><td class='text-center'><input type='submit' class='btn btn-info' value='Notify Donor'></td></tr>");
    }

%>
```

--EDIT--

Requester later specified that he wants to submit the index of row. In that case I would sugest to remove those submit buttons from the table, place radio buttons on each row and have one submit button underneath the table. That submit button would submit only selected radio button's value.
JSP code for the table generation

```
<%

    ArrayList<HospitalDTO> list=(ArrayList<HospitalDTO>)request.getAttribute("arrayList");
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        HospitalDTO hsp = list.get(i);
        long no=hsp.getNumber();
        //session.setAttribute("contactNumber",no);
        String name=hsp.getName();
        Date nextDD=hsp.getNextDD();
        Date lastDD=hsp.getLastDD();

        out.println("<tr><td><input type='radio' value='" + i + "'></td><td class='text-center' >"+no+"</td><td class='text-center'>"+name+"</td><td class='text-center'>" + lastDD + "</td><td class='text-center'>" + nextDD + "</td></tr>");
    }

%>
```

Also, don't forget to wrap everything to a `form` element for submit to work properly.

Comment: Thanks for the code, but this will assign unique id values to each row but what I want is when any of the submit button is clicked then I want to fetch the contact no for that row

Comment: I've marked the answer correct. however, I can't upvote as m repo is less than 15.